# Issues when enabling or disabling optional windows features in C# using PowerShell (System.Management.Automation)

Tags: c#, powershell

I can enable or disable optional windows features using c# but I cant get the contents of the PSOutput properties as PowerShellInst.Streams.Error always catch an error because the command Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature (usually) needs a restart.

So, how i can avoid the "restart-error-message" and get the output results of my script, which will be in my case for example:

```
Path          :
Online        : True
RestartNeeded : True
```

Code used:

```
    string psScript = @"Import-Module Dism; Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process; Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName TelnetClient;";

    using (PowerShell PowerShellInst = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        PowerShellInst.AddScript(psScript);
        Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = PowerShellInst.Invoke();

        if (PowerShellInst.HadErrors) //fires everytime because the installation of an optional feature (usually) need a restart.
        {
            foreach (var error in PowerShellInst.Streams.Error)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(error.ToString()); //"do you want to restart 'error' message" here.
            }
        }

        else
        {
            foreach (var result in PSOutput) //result.Properties content is what i need
            {
                if (result != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(result.Properties["Online"].Value.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine(result.Properties["RestartNeeded"].Value.ToString()); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Give `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -NoRestart` a try

Comment: Thanks, that works perfect!